# ImageView- resize depending on android screen

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a problem and I can't solve it, I will appreciate it if somebody would help me. I want to put two images on the top of the screen. Both images should have width = screen_width/2 (just because when the screen is smaller, images should resize).I've tried this, but it isn't enough. Thank you!

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/imagelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/r"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"    
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" 
        android:background="@drawable/back" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resulttext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/r"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/r"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/r"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/r"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference : http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CC0QtwIwAg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DmlojNcvoW68&ei=RoX4U8zwLdbvaKmOgMgH&usg=AFQjCNE5rRlHfVw-n_jgZAXEhK-Q1dd_Mg&sig2=mt8454k4FzqoVBprIqorNg&bvm=bv.73612305,d.d2s

```
<RelativeLayout                                //Change this to a linear layout
android:id="@+id/imagelayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 

  android:weightSum="2" >                   //add this to linear layout attribute

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/r"
    android:layout_width="0dp"          //change width to 0dp (in case of horzontal layout)
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"    
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" 
    android:background="@drawable/back" 

    android:layour_weight = "1"/>         //add this to both view

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/resulttext"
    android:layout_width="0dp"           //change width to 0dp (in case of horzontal layout)
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/r"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/r"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/r"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/r"

    android:layour_weight = "1"/>         //add this to both view/>
</RelativeLayout>                             //This again has to be linear layout
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LinearLayout instead/inside RelativeLayout and set the weight property to 0.5 in each child view. you should also use layout:gravity to set the child view on the top.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private int columnWidth;
//get Screen Size
public int getScreenWidth() {
            int columnWidth ;
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) this
                    .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

            final Point point = new Point();
            try {
                display.getSize(point);
            } catch (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError ignore) { // Older device
                point.x = display.getWidth();
                point.y = display.getHeight();
            }                              
            columnWidth = point.x;
            return columnWidth;
        }

 //set height and width of Imageview
int height=columnWidth;
int width=columnWidth;
img.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(height,width));
```

Hope this may help you